Sharepoint DriveItem permissions list empty for read-only shared item
I have an application that uses Graph API to access driveItems from a sharepoint site.
The items are shared with users by sharing them with a group. The group only has read access to the item.
In my application I want to check the permissions list of an item (to know via which group the user has access). I do this like so:
 var permissions = await _graphServiceClient
     .Drives[driveItem.ParentReference?.DriveId]
     .Items[driveItem.Id]
     .Permissions
     .GetAsync();

When I am the owner of the item in sharepoint, this returns a list of permissions and I can get the group information out. However as a regular user with only read access via the group, the list of permissions is empty.
The application has the delegated File.Read.All permission, but this appears to make no difference.
Why is the permission list still empty for my read-only users?
